# How do I delete the 2nd to last line in a txt file using batch?

Tags: batch-file

I've searched this site MANY times and found MANY related questions but none were exactly like my question so... I merely need to delete the 2nd to last line in a txt file (%txtfile%.txt) and that's all. The reason it's the 2nd to last is because the file was made using `echo.Sample text>>"%txtfile%.txt"` and so it left an emty line at the end. I now want to delete the last line EXCEPT for the blank line. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition of last line is different then mine. The pair of characters `<CarriageReturn><LineFeed>` terminate a line. At the end of your file you have a line that is terminated, and nothing after it. If you open the file in a text editor and go to the end of the file, the cursor will be on an empty line. But that line is not part of the current file. In my mind, the last line is the line above.

You can Use FIND to determine the number of lines. FIND also does not consider there to be a line after the last line terminator. Then use FINDSTR to prefix each line with the line number piped to a second FINDSTR to filter out the "last" line. A FOR loop reads the output and SET search and replace removes the line number prefix. Delayed expansion is toggled on and off within the loop to protect against `!` being corrupted if it is found within the content of the file during the expansion of the %%L variable.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set file="test.txt"
for /f %%N in ('find /c /v "" ^<%file%') do set skip=%%N
(
  for /f "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /n "^" %file%^|findstr /v "^%skip%:"') do (
    set "ln=%%L"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)>%file%.new
move %file%.new %file% >nul
```

After running the code above, the desired line will have been stripped out. The last line will still be terminated, so a text editor will still show an empty line after the end of the file.

Comment: Good except one thing... You may have misunderstood when i said 2nd to last line because if i have a file that says hello, wazzup, and l8r on seperate lines it will delete wazzup. I meant for it to delete l8r but because there is a default extra space it needs to skip the extra space...

Comment: @VDgames - Then don't subtract one from the line count. I've edited my answer.